# Should I use "providing" or "provided" in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, tenses

These are the sentences I created:

"T.O.P’s mother (Big Bang): ‘My son is in a very critical condition'.

The first time SHARING with journalists, mother of a Big Bang member said he still had been in unconscious condition. She said that the information from the police's side PROVIDED before was completely wrong."

Are they grammatically correct? Is the verb SHARING correct? And Should I use "PROVIDING" or "PROVIDED" in the last sentence?

Comment: "She said" directly point to past tense. No need to judge either with providing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following:

"The first time SHARING with journalists, **the** mother of a Big Bang member said he still had been in **an** unconscious condition. She said that the information previously provided by the police was completely wrong."

Provided was correct, but the sentence structure seemed a little awkward to me,  and you were missing a few articles, which I typed in bold font in the revised sentence.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll learn from this experience.

Comment: @PeterNguyen, you might also think about writing ". . . he still had been unconscious" rather than ". . . he still had been in an unconscious condition" as there is only a single unconsciousness, and hence, only a single unconscious condition.